# Plot x y data from different files/tables

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have two data files (`xxxx.txt` and `yyyy.txt`), each only containing one column of x and y data respectively. Now I want to plot these two data together in a simple 2D diagram. Has anybody an idea how this is possible?

Until now I always had my x and y data in one file together (two columns, first x, second y). So there was no problem and I plotted my data like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
   \addplot table {datatable.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Does anybody have a helpful idea or solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, `pgfplotstable` allows you to define something like "virtual columns", which are created once you try to access them (either in an `\addplot table` command or using `\pgfplotstabletypeset` for example), which can acquire data in a variety of ways. One of the creation methods for these virtual columns is `copy column from table={<table or file name>}{<column name>}`.

If you set

```
\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/Y/.style={create col/copy column from table={dataB.txt}{0}}
}
```

then whenever you try to access column `Y` (of whatever table), the data from `dataB.txt` will be used:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{dataA.txt}
2
3
4
5
3
5
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{dataB.txt}
5
4
3
2
5
5
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/Y/.style={create col/copy column from table={dataB.txt}{0}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [y=Y] {dataA.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```